# For $n \geq 2$, find an epimorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find an epimorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$; assume $n \ge 2$.

$S_n = \{\iota, \sigma_1, . . . \}$

Let $\phi(\sigma) = \Bigg\{ \begin{array}{cc}0: \sigma = \iota\\1: \sigma \neq \iota \end{array}   $

So if it is the identity permutation it maps to $0 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ else it will map to $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

$\phi(\iota) = 0 \\ \phi(\sigma_{\neq\iota}) = 1$

$\phi(\iota\sigma) = 0 +_2 1 = \phi(\iota) +_2 \phi(\sigma) =1 \\
\phi(\iota\iota) = 0 +_2 0 = \phi(\iota) +_2 \phi(\iota) =0  \\
\phi(\sigma\sigma) = 1 +_2 1 = \phi(\sigma) +_2 \phi(\sigma) =0 \\
\phi(\sigma\iota) = 1 +_2 0 = \phi(\sigma) +_2 \phi(\iota) =1
$

It is onto, is that an adequate epimorphism?

Comment: For $n\ge 3$, your suggestion is not a homomorphism since for instance we should have $0=\phi(\iota)=\phi((123)(123)(123))=\phi(123)+\phi(123)+\phi(123)=1+1+1=1$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Comment: maybe if I change it to $\phi(\sigma_{even}) = 0$ and $\phi(\sigma_{odd}) = 1$ ?

then $\phi(\sigma_{odd}\sigma_{odd}) = 1 +_2 1 = 0 = \phi(\sigma_{odd}) +_2 \phi(\sigma_{odd})$ ,


$\phi(\sigma_{even}\sigma_{odd}) = 0 +_2 1 = 1 = \phi(\sigma_{even}) +_2 \phi(\sigma_{odd})$,


$\phi(\sigma_{even}\sigma_{even}) = 0 +_2 0 = 0 = \phi(\sigma_{even}) +_2 \phi(\sigma_{even})$,


$\phi(\sigma_{odd}\sigma_{even}) = 1 +_2 0 = 1 = \phi(\sigma_{odd}) +_2 \phi(\sigma_{even})$

Comment: That would work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by paw88789 in the comments, your proposed map is not a homomorphism.

Your second attempt however is correct; it is called the sign or signature homomorphism. In this context, we usually consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the multiplicative group $\{1, -1\}$. Doing this, the sign homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn} : S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^m$ where $m$ is the number of transpositions in a decomposition of $\sigma$. Although different decompositions of $\sigma$ into transpositions could give different values of $m$, the value $(-1)^m$ is the same (i.e. the number of transpositions is always even or always odd).

It is worth noting that $\operatorname{sgn}$ is still a homomorphism for $n = 1$, but it is no longer surjective, so it is not an epimorphism.